# Analytics on an angularjs web application

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

We're building a new web dashboard-type application in Angularjs (single-page-application SPA).  Would love to know if there is a good service that would help with visualization of usage of the system.

Don't care about funnels, conversions, content, etc.  Most analytics services seem to be too "content/conversion" oriented

Question: would like to find if there are any tracking services, that can let us know which screens/tabs are users using the most. Which screens they're cancelling out of.  Information would be most useful if it was on a user-by-user basis.
(We dont have millions of users, so individual user tracking is totally manageable from data quantity perspective)

Any suggestions?
TIA

Comment: I've re-edited the question, but I'm not sure why it is too broad.  I would imagine tracking software that specializes on angularjs would be a rare thing and the few apps/vendors that might exist out there would be very userful to know about

Comment: Unfortunately this would also be considered as asking for [recommendations](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which is off-topic here since that leads to spam and self-promotional answers. You could try asking this over at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but be sure to read the FAQ in their Help Center first.